# Counting problem for seating in a circle

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

I am having a hard time understanding the answer to the following problem from Grimaldi:

"At Professor Alfred's science camp, 17 students have lunch together each day at a circular table. They are trying to get to know one another better, so they make an effort to sit next to two different colleagues each afternoon. For how many afternoons can they do this? How can they arrange themselves on these occasions?"

They have solved it in the context of Hamilton cycles, which I have not understood at all. I have a feeling it can be solved by some other method of counting also. 
Any help will be nice..

Comment: There is an upper bound of $\frac{17-1}{2}=8$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As we see each student can be neighbor of two students each time, we have a lower bound of afternoons they need, $\frac{17-1}{2}=8$. We can show that this lower bound can be reached if we can partition edges of the complete graph $K_{17}$ into $8$ Hamiltonian circuits, where we see a Hamiltonian circuit as a seating plan in a natural way. And we can do it indeed:

We see vertices of $K_{17}$ as elements of group $\mathbb{Z}_{17}=\{0,1,2,\dots,16\}$. Define $C_i=\{\{a,a+i\}\mid a\in\mathbb{Z}_{17}\}$. Then, $C_1,C_2,\dots,C_8$ form a required partition.

Comment: Can you pls elaborate on how we got this lower bound of 8?

Comment: @inquisitive Imagine, you are one of the student, each meal you have meet $2$ students, if you want to meet them all, $16$, you need $8$ meals.

Comment: Oh it seems so easy after your explanation! thanks.